# Laptop screen suddenly dim

Tags: laptop

So I dropped my phone on my Asus Laptop right above the keyboard, in the middle, right where the battery is. The screen became really dim, and I can only see a little bit. A few minutes later it randomly shut off... So is this inverter or Battery problem. The screen is the same brightness when plugged in and not plugged in

Comment: What are the work around you have tried so far.

Comment: Try without battery and run in power adapter and check.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to adjust the screen brightness by using the adjustment keys on the keyboard.

They are right about where you say the phone dropped.